# How do I keep my SwiftUI previews from running in the background after I close them?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode-previews

I am developing a game with Swift / Xcode / SwiftUI, and Xcode's preview window is great for iterating on changes quickly. But I noticed that when I close the preview canvas, my app is still running in Activity Monitor, taking up lots of CPU, even though Xcode's preview window is not showing--and I usually run `killall MyAppName` on the terminal to stop the process. You can also tell that it's still running because it still responds to game controller input and plays sound effects! (If I don't kill the app, all my subsequent builds are slower, since my laptop is still running my game in the background while building...)

As far as I can tell, my normal AppDelegate methods are not getting called in a preview context, so catching things like `application(application:, didDiscardSceneSesssions:)` doesn't work for this problem. I tried overriding `application(application: didDiscardSceneSessions:)`, but it wasn't called.

Anyone have any ideas for how to "tell" that my app, when running as a preview, is "not showing" as a preview anymore? I'd like to have it automatically kill its own process, or I guess ideally gracefully quit.